# Problem with .shadowColor with CustomUIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibutton

I subclassed UIButton to make a custom gradient background for my UIButtons.
The UIButtons are hooked up correctly and it works flawlessly.

When I however try to add a red shadow it gets added but it is always gray. It ignores my .shadowColor statement. Here the relevant code.

```
@implementation CustomUIButton
...
    -(void)awakeFromNib
    {
    ...
    [self titleLabel].shadowColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self titleLabel].shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);
    ...
    }
...
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIButton` instances need to know for which control state you want to set the color. Try the following method.

```
[self setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```